# PDO Array to String Conversion - Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, parameters

Pretty sure there's an easy fix for this, but I'm inexperienced in array handling when it comes to PDO statements

Purpose: To retrieve a set of id's from the database, then use those ids to compare and retrieve

```
$SAList = getSecurityActionsForQuestion("$QID");
$con = database::getInstance()->getConnection();
$ParentList = $con->prepare('SELECT SQ.SurveyQuestionID, SQ.SurveyQuestionDesc 
FROM SurveyQuestion SQ
JOIN  SurveyQuestionLookup SQLP ON SQLP.SurveyQuestionID = SQ.SurveyQuestionID
WHERE SQLP.SecurityActionID IN (:SAList)
   AND SQLP.SurveyQuestionID != :QID');
$ParentList->bindValue(':QID',$QID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ParentList->bindValue(':SAList',$SAList, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$ParentList->execute();
$Results = $ParentList->fetchAll();
```

Now, individually, both the 'getSecurityActionForQuestion' function and the inserted select statement work and retrieve what I want. The issue is that I cannot send an array into the PDO::PARAM_STR and I have not found a fix for this.

I have seen some options to implode and prepare the string, but I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate this into my current design.

There is a possibility of using a foreach loop that creates a new array, holds a count variable and then within the SQL statement, I could insert a bunch of named parameters, then use another for loop to bind each parameter to their respective places, but I'm pretty sure someone out there has a far more elegant process than that hackjob.

EDIT:

Addition of the getSecurityActionsForQuestion(ID) function for clarity

```
function getSecurityActionsForQuestion($QID)
{
    $con = database::getInstance()->getConnection();
    $SAList = $con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT SecurityActionID FROM SurveyQuestionLookup
    WHERE SurveyQuestionID = :QID");
    $SAList->bindValue(':QID',$QID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $SAList->execute();
    $Results = $SAList->fetchAll();
    $SAList=null;
    $con=null;  
    return $Results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` placeholders instead of named placeholders, and execute the query using an array of values rather than binding each value individually. (See example #5 in [the PDOStatement::execute manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).)

```
$SAList = getSecurityActionsForQuestion("$QID");
$con = database::getInstance()->getConnection();

// create placeholders for each item in your array
$placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($SAList)),',');

$ParentList = $con->prepare("SELECT SQ.SurveyQuestionID, SQ.SurveyQuestionDesc 
FROM SurveyQuestion SQ
JOIN  SurveyQuestionLookup SQLP ON SQLP.SurveyQuestionID = SQ.SurveyQuestionID
WHERE SQLP.SecurityActionID IN ($placeholders)
   AND SQLP.SurveyQuestionID != ?");

// add the $QID into the array
$SAList[] = $QID;

// execute the query with the array of values
$ParentList->execute($SAList);

$Results = $ParentList->fetchAll();
```

`PDO::PARAM_STR` is the default binding type, so it will be used for this without specifying it.

Comment: I like this solution, but is there anyway to sanitize the information to try and prevent SQL injection? I know that it's an internal function, so it shouldn't be readily interceptable, but it would be still good to know

Comment: This has the same effect as binding the values individually, and using this method shouldn't negate any positive effects of using prepared statements. Because the only thing you're directly inserting into your SQL is the placeholders, and the parameters are still passed and bound separately, this way shouldn't increase your SQL injection vulnerability. It's just a shorter way to do the same thing.

Comment: That's odd. I am still receiving the array to string conversion error with your code.

EDIT: Also, can $placeholders be accessed while within the "" tags, or should it the "" be replaced with '' and have the concatenation of the $placeholders variable? I've never not separated variables from strings, so I'm not sure if that's something that can be done, stupid me, I know.

Comment: on which statement?

Comment: $ParentList->execute($SAList);

Comment: $placeholders can be accessed within the quotations. Variables are parsed in strings quoted with `"` instead of `'`. [Here's the relevant PHP manual section.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: Is `$SAList` just an array of strings? It seems like you shouldn't get that error unless there is an array in it somewhere.

Comment: It's an array of numbers (Held as strings in the array of course). (For the test, I only have one at the moment, but it should still make an array of 1 entry) I could post the function/vardump if it would help?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be helpful. I'll admit I'm a bit confused. :)

Comment: You and me both - added.

Comment: Without specifying a fetch style in the `fetchAll()` method, it will use whatever default fetch mode you have set which probably means that your `getSecurityActionsForQuestion` function is returning an array of arrays, each with one ID. Try using `$Results = $SAList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` instead.

Comment: BEAUTY. I had forgotten about that! Thanks for the clarification!  Works